# About the proof of Implicit Function Theorem (For Three Variables :F(x,y,z)=0)

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

It is a three variables version of IFT, and the proof I found on a website given as follows:

WLOG, the set S can be taken to be a parallelpiped, a box,centered on P because within the set S there will be at least one such box. Within any such box there will be another box containing P such that ∂F/∂z has the the same sign as at P. Let the box be given as a triple (a,b,c) such that

|x-x0| ≤ a |y-y0| ≤ b |z-z0| ≤ c

WLOG, the sign of ∂F/∂z at P can be taken to be positive.

This means that

F(x0,y0,z0+c) > 0 F(x0,y0,z0-c) < 0

Now consider any point (x1,y1) such that

|x1-x0| ≤ a |y1-y0| ≤ b

**Because F(x0,y0,z0+c) > 0 and F(x,y,z) is continuous, F(x1,y1,z0+c) > 0. Likewise F(x1,y1,z0-c) < 0.** With x and y held fixed at x1 and y1, G(z)=F(x1,y1,z) is a function such that G(z0+c) > 0 and G(z0-c) < 0. Therefore there is some z between z0-c and z0+c such that G(z)=0; i.e., F(x1,y1,z)=0. Moreover this value of z is unique. Since this holds for any (x,y) such |x-x0| ≤ a |y-y0| ≤ b

over this domain there exists a function z=f(x,y) such that F(x,y,z)=0.

**I don't understand why by continuity of F(x,y,z) F(x1,y1,z0+c) has the same signs as F(x0,y0,z0+c).**

It confuses me a lot. Hope anyone could help!!

Big thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I have received some replies, you can check it if you are interested : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some hypotheses which you should add (or didn't tell about?). $F$ is obviously assumed continuous but also $\partial F/\partial z$ should be assumed continuous. Then there is a story concerning 'choices'. Given the first parallelepiped you may shrink $a$ and $b$ so as to satisfy the condition you mention and keeping the sign of $\partial F/\partial z$. From that the argument works. Sort of nice as it does not assume $F$ to be $C^1$ in all variables.

Comment: so you are saying that the open neighborhood of P(x0,y0,z0) should satisfy two conditions at the same time , one is that  ∂F/∂z has the the same sign as at P, another is F(x1,y1,z0+c) has the same sign as F(x0,y0,z0+c)?

Comment: Yes, in fact you want $F(x1,y1,-c)<0<F(x1,y1,c)$ for every $x1,y1$ in a sufficiently small rectangle and the partial derivative to be positive everywhere in the parallelepiped. Then for each $x1,y1$ you may apply the argument to find $z$ so that $F(x1,y1,z)=0$.

Comment: why x1,y1, should be in a sufficiently small rectangle? I thought F(x1,y1,−c)<0<F(x1,y1,c) should be true for all x,y in that open neighborhood of P where the partial derivatives w.r.t z to be positive, so that I can get z = f(x,y) for all x,y in that open neighborhood.

Comment: It is not automatic. You first choose $c$ to assure the condition for $x0,y0$ and then   $ a , b$ in order to assure the condition in a neighborhood.

Comment: Thanks ! I think I get it !